# How to use quote " character in XAML binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, quotes

I'm trying to do this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text, 
           Converter={StaticResource stringFormatConverter}, 
           ConverterParameter='\"{0}\"'}" />
```

But this is apparently not the way to get a quote into a XAML binding string.

What is the appropriate way to get "\"{0}"\" to work here?

Comment: yeah, you can see the code now

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have two options:

```
"&quot;{0}&quot;"
'"{0}"'
```

This is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748250.aspx

In your example (I couldn't see what you were trying to do at first), you'll probably want to do:

```
...='&quot;{0}&quot;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I add "%" after binding text in windows phone.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=clouds.all, StringFormat=\{0\}%}"/>
```

Comment: But you don't add quotes. How does this help?

Comment: For those wanting quotes using the StringFormat method given here, this will give quoted text

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=my_string, StringFormat='&quot;{0}&quot;'}"/>